# what is the asymptotic expansion of this $_2F_2$ function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, power-series

We need to expand the function $_2F_2(a+b x,1; 1+a+b x, b x; x)$ near $x=+\infty$. Where $a$ is complex, $b>1$.

When $x\to+\infty$, both the parameters and the variable goes to infinity, we can not used the expansion formulas only for large parameters or only for large variable.

Any comments and references are welcomed.

***Update***
Because
$${_1F_1}(a;c;x)=\lim_{b\to\infty}{_2F_1}(a,b;c;x/b)$$

We have
$$\lim_{y\to\infty}{_2F_2}(a+b x,1; 1+a+b x, b y;y)=_2F_1(a+b x,1; 1+a+b x;1/b)$$

So the leading term seems to to be $ _1F_0(1; ;1/b)=b/(b-1)$

Comment: May I ask why this is tagged `riemann-zeta`?

Comment: It showed up in our ongoing search of approximations to Riemann $\Xi(z)$ function.

Comment: @mike then explain (in a few words) the link with $\Xi(z)$

Comment: @user1952009. It takes too long to explain it. So I decided to delete the tag of Riemann Zeta.

Comment: you won't get any answer if you don't explain how it is interesting in the context of $\zeta(s)$